# Non-homogenous recurrence relation. How to find the particular solution?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have enclosed one image of two textbook pages.
There is a system of equation (see frame) on page 2.
I do not understand why both terms can be set equal to 0 (zero)to solve it.
Thank you for the assistance.[image]

Comment: @Hello David, yes correct. But I'm not sure why they set it equal to zero to solve it. I do not understand the intermediate step.

Comment: If the expression on the last line of the left hand page has to be uniformly zero for all n, we must set the coefficient of n to zero. That's what they did, and I believe that is your question

Answer (score 1):

The argument they're making is a fairly common one.  When you have two polynomials $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, you can say they're equal if each corresponding coefficient is equal.  As an example, $f(x)=(4a)x^2+(2b)x+1$ is equal to $g(x)=3x+1$ precisely when $4a=0$, $2b=3$, and $1=1$.  Hopefully that concept makes sense, now to get into their argument.

They started with $An+B=3A(n-1)+3B+n$.  This is actually two polynomials in $n$.  To see this, first I'm going to simplify the right-hand side:
\begin{align}
3A(n-1)+3B+n&=3An-3A+3B+n \\
&=\underbrace{(3A+1)}_{a_1}n+\underbrace{(3B-3A)}_{a_0} \\
&=a_1n+a_0
\end{align}
It should be clear from the above that the right-hand side is a degree 1 polynomial in $n$, with certain coefficients.  So, I have some polynomial (for the left-hand side) $f(n)=An+B$, and on the right-hand side I have $g(n)=(3A+1)n+(3B-3A)$.  These will be equal precisely when the constant terms are equal, and when the coefficients in front of the $n$ term are equal.  So, we would say that:

$$3A+1=A\quad\text{ and}$$
$$B=3B-3A$$
These two equations can be rearranged into $2A+1=0$ and $2B-3A=0$, which is the system of equations the book gets to.